# How to delete entire row of the table on click checkbox of that row in angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a table whose data is coming from loop.Here when you press add button new similar row will be added at just bottom.Again when you press edit button all textbox will be enable(initially disable).Till now working fine.But when I check single checkbox or multiple checkbox and press delete button all the row based on checked checkbox will be delete/remove.Again when I click delete button without selecting any checkbox alert message should display and also when user selected all check boxes and tried to delete all the row an alert message should be there that 'at least one row should be there' and he cannot delete all rows unless any one row will be unchecked.I am new to angular can anyone please help me.Here is the code below https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wscsmy

### app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Basic Table</h2>
    <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>
    <div><button (click)="enable()">Edit</button> &nbsp;
    <button (click)="delete()">Delete</button> </div>
    <table class="table border">

        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let row of groups;let i = index" (click)="setClickedRow(i)"  [class.active]="i == selectedRow">
              <td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
                <td> <input #focus [disabled]='toggleButton' type="text" value="{{row.name}}"> </td>
                <td> <input [disabled]='toggleButton' type="text" value="{{row.items}}"> </td>
                <td> <button (click)="addRow(i)">Add</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  selectedRow: Number;

  @ViewChild('focus', { static: false }) input: ElementRef;
  public toggleButton: boolean = true;
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  groups = [
    {
      "name": "pencils",
      "items": "red pencil"
    },
    {
      "name": "rubbers",
      "items": "big rubber"
    },
    {
      "name": "rubbers1",
      "items": "big rubber1"
    },
  ];
  addRow(index): void {
    var currentElement = this.groups[index];
    this.groups.splice(index, 0, currentElement);
  }
  enable() {
    this.toggleButton = false
    setTimeout(() => { // this will make the execution after the above boolean has changed
      this.input.nativeElement.focus();
      this.selectedRow = 0;
    }, 0);
  }
  delete(){
    alert('hello');
  }
  setClickedRow(index) {
    this.selectedRow = index;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an array to keep track of the state of each checkbox. And update it every time a checkbox is checked or unchecked.

**Template:**

```
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" (click)="toggleSelection($event, i)" [checked]="checkboxes[i]">
</td>
```

**Component:**

```
checkboxes: boolean[];

ngOnInit() {
   this.checkboxes = new Array(this.groups.length);
   this.checkboxes.fill(false);
}

toggleSelection(event, i) {
  this.checkboxes[i] = event.target.checked;
}
```

Also, add another checkbox entry to the array whenever a new row is added.

```
addRow(index): void {
  // Other code.
  this.checkboxes.splice(index, 0, false);
}
```

You can use [Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to delete elements from an array.

[Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) can be used to check if at least one checkbox is selected, and  [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) can be used to check if all the checkboxes are selected.

```
delete() {
  var atleastOneSelected = this.checkboxes.some(checkbox => checkbox === true);
  var allSelected = this.checkboxes.every(checkbox => checkbox === true);

  if (!atleastOneSelected) {
    alert("No rows selected.");
    return;
  }

  if (allSelected) {
    alert("At least one row should be present.");
    return;
  }

  // Iterating in reverse to avoid index conflicts by in-place deletion.
  for (let i = this.checkboxes.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // If selected, then delete that row.
    if (this.checkboxes[i]) {
      this.groups.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  // Remove entries from checkboxes array.
  this.checkboxes = this.checkboxes.filter(checkbox => checkbox === false);
}
```

Live demo on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-abhkyk

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,here on check of multiple checkbox and when you click delete button all checked row should be delete. Also validations mentioned in the above question are not working

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER - Yes, I noticed that in your question right now. I'll update the answer soon.

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER - Check out my updated answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Validations are working fine.But If I select 2 rows out of 3 and try to delete its deleting only one, it should delete both selected. Even I add rows by clicking add button and try to delete same thing happening

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER - Fixed it. Updated the answer. Check out StackBlitz to see it working.

Comment: I used this in my project but I am getting type error that 'length is undefined' for  this line this.checkboxes = new Array(this.groups.length); also this line (click)="toggleSelection($event, i)" ' some thing like 'null value cannot be 0'

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER - `this.checkboxes = new Array(this.groups.length); ` statement should be placed after `groups` data is available. Not sure about second error, but I'll take a look if you can post a link to complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper array, where you store all the checked checkboxes. Before deletion, check that at least one value is present.

I choose to store the indexes of the items to the helper array, and based on that, delete from the original array. So perhaps something like this:

```ts
toBeDeleted = [];

// called when button is clicked
delete() {
  if (!this.toBeDeleted.length) {
    alert('Choose at least one!');
  } else if (this.toBeDeleted.length === this.groups.length) {
      alert('You cannot delete all rows')
  } 
  else {
    this.groups = this.groups.filter((currentValue, index, arr) => !this.toBeDeleted.includes(index));
  }
  // reset the array
  this.toBeDeleted = [];
}


remove(event, index) {
  // check if checkbox is checked, if so, push to array, else delete from array
  if (event.target.checked) {
    this.toBeDeleted.push(index)
  } else {
    const idx = this.toBeDeleted.indexOf(index);
    this.toBeDeleted.splice(idx, 1)
  }
}
```

Then in your template, when user clicks on checkbox, call `remove()` and pass the `$event` and index of item:

```ts
 <td> <input type="checkbox" (click)="remove($event, i)"></td>
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-86k7vx?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer but last point of validation is not working,I mean if you selected all and tried to delete , alert message will be there that 'at least one row should be there' and he cannot delete all rows unless any one row will be unchecked

Comment: I cannot reproduce that issue, works fine on my stackblitz over here...?

Comment: Till now every thing is fine,but one more validation we have that user cannot delete all the rows,at least one row should be there in the table always.But here on checked all checkbox I can able to delete all the rows

Comment: Everything is working fine but when I add rows by clicking add button  and check all rows except one that time also alert message is showing ' choose at least one row'  and if I check randomly, some time checked row not deleting,deleting other rows