# Delete table rows on check of checkboxes are not working in angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a table consists of some data coming from loop,Here on click of edit button,add buttons and textboxes will be enable,again on check of multiple checkboxes add buttons will be disable,again on uncheck of multiple checkboxes(Leaving one checkbox) add button will be enable.Till here every thing fine.Now if I check any rows and click delete that selected rows should be deleted and if I click delete button without selecting any checkbox an validation message that 'at least one should be selected'.Here is the code I tried
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wscsmy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  selectedRow: Number;
  count:number = 0;
  @ViewChild('focus', { static: false }) input: ElementRef;
  public toggleButton: boolean = true;
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  groups = [
    {
      "name": "pencils",
      "items": "red pencil"
    },
    {
      "name": "rubbers",
      "items": "big rubber"
    },
    {
      "name": "rubbers1",
      "items": "big rubber1"
    },
  ];
  addRow(index): void {
    var currentElement = this.groups[index];
    this.groups.splice(index, 0, currentElement);
  }
  enable() {
    this.toggleButton = false
    setTimeout(() => { // this will make the execution after the above boolean has changed
      this.input.nativeElement.focus();
      this.selectedRow = 0;
    }, 0);
  }
  delete(){
    alert('hello');
  }
  changed(){
    this.count = 0;
    this.groups.forEach(item=>{
if(item.selected==true){
  this.count = this.count+1;
  if(this.count>1){
    this.toggleButton =true;
  }
  else{
  this.toggleButton = false;  
  }
}
    })
  }
  setClickedRow(index) {
    this.selectedRow = index;
  }
}
```

### app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Basic Table</h2>
    <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>
    <div><button (click)="enable()">Edit</button> &nbsp;
    <button (click)="delete()">Delete</button> </div>
    <table class="table border">

        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let row of groups;let i = index" (click)="setClickedRow(i)"  [class.active]="i == selectedRow">
              <td> <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="row.selected" (ngModelChange)="changed()" (click)="clickc(row.selected)"></td>
                <td> <input #focus [disabled]='toggleButton' type="text" value="{{row.name}}"> </td>
                <td> <input [disabled]='toggleButton' type="text" value="{{row.items}}"> </td>
                <td> <button [disabled]='toggleButton' (click)="addRow(i)">Add</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What seems to be the issue? You asked this question before and accepted an answer. Answer also has live demo to do what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58016805/6294072 You have since then apparently omitted the code presented there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the checked row will be deleted. Here is the working sample:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n3qgbm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

You should add to your objects additional property "selected" with default value "false" and update your **delete()** method, how I did:

**Your objects:**

```
  groups = [
    {
      "name": "pencils",
      "items": "red pencil",
      "selected": false
    },
    {
      "name": "rubbers",
      "items": "big rubber",
      "selected": false
    },
    {
      "name": "rubbers1",
      "items": "big rubber1",
      "selected": false
    },
  ];
```

**delete() method:**

```
  delete(){
    let checkedRows: Array<any> = [];
    let uncheckedRows: Array<any> = this.groups;
    this.groups = this.groups.filter((row: any) => {
      if (row.selected !== false) {
        checkedRows.push(row);
      } else {
        return row;
      }
    });
    if (checkedRows.length === 0) {
      alert('At least one should be selected!');
    }
    if (checkedRows.length === uncheckedRows.length) {
      alert('At least one row should be there unchecked!');
      this.groups = checkedRows;
    }
  }
```

It works for me) Good luck

Comment: Thank you,if I click delete button without selecting any checkbox an validation message that 'at least one should be selected'  not there

Comment: Sorry) you are right. I've just updated this sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n3qgbm?file=src/app/app.component.ts. Now it works how you wanted) Try it please)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I need one more help that if I select all the checkboxes and click delete button , a validation should be there that user cannot delete all rows onclick of delete button,at least one row should be there unchecked..

Comment: Not the best solution, but it works so, as you wanted)) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n3qgbm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Hope, it'll help you) Good luck